# Javascript str.replace with html string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, str-replace

EDIT:

in order to be more exhaustive:

I've a dynamic page generated by an external server-side rendering engine (the ERP solution handle the e-commerce too, bad story...) that add its own part of code, like buttons, input form etc. 
I cannot directly control them but and I need to style them.
So I'm using the string replace function of js because I cannot use php, just html/js. But I don't know js, I'm just learning it, and in this case I haven't had things working because of lack of knowledge about syntax / escaping.

The `function` is loaded with `onload="function ()"` in the body.

I've just added a `<div id="replace-input">` outside the parts of the code needed to be replaced (in this case is an input form for the qty of items to be sended into the cart)

thanks

END EDIT

I cannot find a working solution to replace an html string like

```
<input name="qty" id="qty" size="6" maxlength="6" value="1" class="input">
```

into another one like

```
<div class="product-qty">
<label for="qty">Qty:</label>
<div class="custom-qty">
<button type="button" class="reduced items" onclick="var result = document.getElementById('qty');   var qty = result.value;  if (!isNaN(qty) &amp;&amp; qty > 1)result.value--; return false;"> <i class="fa fa-minus-square-o"></i> </button> 
<input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty"> 
<button type="button" class="increase items" onclick="var result = document.getElementById('qty');   var qty = result.value;  if (!isNaN(qty)) result.value++;return false;"> <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i> </button>
</div>
</div>
```

I'm using this function

```
var str = document.getElementById("replace-input").innerHTML; 
    var res = str.replace(/HereIHaveToAddTheFirstString/g, "HereTheSecondOne");
    document.getElementById("replace-input").innerHTML = res;
```

but I don't know how to write the strings in order to be parsed correctly.

Comment: Why dont you use the DOM methods to manipulate the elements and/or their attributes instead of trying to do string manipulation? Also you shouldn't use inline js like that it will end up being hard for you to manage

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I want to change (replace) elements that are dynamically generated by an external rendering engine of the framework from which the page is generated.

Comment: Your function refers to `.getElementById("replace-input")`but I see no such element in your DOM. It's unclear what exactly you want to replace with what.

Comment: From what I understand, OP wants to pass blocks of HTML code as strings to JS variables. I think it's just a matter of knowing how to escape the special characters. I

Comment: Yeah is that. I haven't other choices because I can manipulate some elements of the DOM after haved them generated by server-side third party engine.

Comment: Although you made it work, instead of using str.replace, you should follow Patrick's advice so I updated my answer to show you how to manipulate the HTML elements

Comment: Ok thank you very much :) I'll follow your suggestions!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you're looking for a way to use the HTML code as strings, you can use an online [tool](http://www.accessify.com/tools-and-wizards/developer-tools/html-javascript-convertor/) to escape the characters for you. After that, you should use DOM manipulation to replace the two elements. If jQuery is not an option, you can do something like

```
var div = document.createElement('div');

div.className = 'product-qty';

div.innerHTML = "<label for=\"qty\">Qty:<\/label>"
+ "<div class=\"custom-qty\">"
+ "<button type=\"button\" class=\"reduced items\" onclick=\"var result = document.getElementById('qty');   var qty = result.value;  if (!isNaN(qty) &amp;&amp; qty > 1)result.value--; return false;\"> <i class=\"fa fa-minus-square-o\"><\/i> <\/button> "
+ "<input type=\"text\" name=\"qty\" id=\"qty\" maxlength=\"12\" value=\"1\" title=\"Qty\" class=\"input-text qty\"> "
+ "<button type=\"button\" class=\"increase items\" onclick=\"var result = document.getElementById('qty');   var qty = result.value;  if (!isNaN(qty)) result.value++;return false;\"> <i class=\"fa fa-plus-square-o\"><\/i> <\/button>"
+ "<\/div>";

var container = document.getElementById("replace-input");
var element = document.getElementById("qty");

container.removeChild(element);
container.appendChild(div)
```

Comment: It works. Thank you very much :)

Comment: explained better in the last EDIT